# Parsing Complex Json Object in android

Tags: android, json

i want to retrieve following filed  from json object

> From OriginLocation =>> CityCode, DepartureDate, DepartureTime
>
> From DestinationLocation =>> CityCode, ArrivalTime, ArrivalDate
>
> From Fare =>> OrigTotalFareAmt
>
> From FlightDetails ==>> CabinClassCode, JourneyDuration

using one for loop

http://pastie.org/8563070#7

Comment: Any code to demonstrate what have you tried so far?

Comment: http://pastie.org/8563138 i try this using this i got FlightResultID, RefundableFareIndicator, StopsNum

Comment: Have a better look of your json data with `http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/`

Comment: ya did that so what is use of that

Comment: melquiades tell me one think please How to get all data from particular object such as from object OriginLocation =>> CityCode, DepartureDate, DepartureTime

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
private void parseJson(JSONObject data) {

        if (data != null) {
            Iterator<String> it = data.keys();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                String key = it.next();
                try {
                    if (data.get(key) instanceof JSONArray) {
                        JSONArray arry = data.getJSONArray(key);
                        int size = arry.length();
                        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                            parseJson(arry.getJSONObject(i));
                        }
                    } else if (data.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
                        parseJson(data.getJSONObject(key));
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Key :" + key);
                        System.out.println("Value :" + data.getString(key));
                    }
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Key :" + key);
                        System.out.println("Value :" + data.getString(key));
                    } catch (Exception ee) {
                    }
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: tell me one think please How to get all data from particular object such as from  object OriginLocation =>> CityCode, DepartureDate, DepartureTime